# Load csv to Hive removing header

Tags: hive

I have a set of csv files to load into Hive external table. As per system these files should not contain header, but there may be cases where we might receive files with header sometimes. How do I handle such cases?

Comment: How do you "load" the files?

Comment: I load using the below format.                                                         CREATE TABLE temp 
  ( 
     name STRING, 
     id   INT 
  ) 
row format delimited fields terminated BY '\t' lines terminated BY '\n' 
tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1");

Comment: **(1)** This does not load anything, these are just instructions for how to read the files. **(2)** Are all the files in your TEMP directory with/without header?

Comment: Actually hive is not related with the headers in input file. Its mainly works on given schema and order of columns. You must have to maintain the schema.